# Navigation UI обновление

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Сейчас создала новый проект и выбрала шаблон `Navigation Drawer Activity`. Вместо привычных классов и `layout` появились куча классов и `layout`, что поставило меня в тупик.. Полезла читать документацию но пока еще плохо разобралась и остались вопросы.

Например есть классы `HomeViewModel, HomeFragment`.. Скажите пожалуйста для чего нужны оба класса и в каком классе описывать логику в каком модель? Если я правильно понимаю то разработчики решили привести все к `MVC`.

Например если я добавляю `RecyclerView` в `fragment_home.xml`, то как мне с ним работать в классах? Что описать в `HomeViewModel`, а что в `HomeFragment`?

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final Button btnShowActivity = root.findViewById(R.id.btnShowActivity);

        homeViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                btnShowActivity.setText(s);
            }
        });

        return root;
    }
}

public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    public HomeViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mText.setValue("This is home fragment");
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что с момента выхода Android Jetpack добавилось много новых инструментов и одним из этих инструментов является [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).
ViewModel чаще всего представляет из себя презентер для таких архитектур как [MVP](https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/493-mvp-dlja-nachinajuschih-bez-bibliotek-i-interfejsov.html) или [MVVM](https://stfalcon.com/ru/blog/post/android-mvvm).
Т.е в ViewModel вы описываете логику, а работа с данными ложится на плечи Model, ViewModel запрашивает их у Model и далее обновляется UI данными пришедшими из Model.
Перевод офф.примера [приложения](https://habr.com/ru/post/456256/) с использованием всего этого добра (ссылка на источник есть в статье).
Насчет RecyclerView, мы помним, что ViewModel это презентер, а любой презентер обычно начинает работать после взаимодействия пользователя с кнопками и т.п. из этого выходит, что можно организовать вложенный интефейс в классе адаптера - [пример](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/).
В случае MVVM [реализация](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/android-recyclerview-using-mvvm-and-databinding-d9c659236908) будет другой + нужно разобраться в [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.. Правильно ли я поняла что HomeViewModel нужно писать логику? Т.е. инициализацию адаптера и другие работы с RecyclerView. А что тогда делает класс HomeFragment?

Comment: Да, верно. Фрагмент является средством для отображения данных и для взаимодействия с пользователем.

Comment: А в HomeFragment  могу ли  я писать какие-то методы, который работают с UI элементами? Например чтобы по нажатию на кнопку появлялось Toast. Это писать в HomeFragment  или HomeViewModel? Просто я смотрю в HomeFragment  была инициализация TextView, а текст для него берется из ViewModel и это меня путает

Comment: Да, во фрагменте Вы можете как обычно работать со слушателями,  инициализировать view и тд, главное отделить логику, её в activity/fragment быть не должно. В случае mvvm все иначе, советую почитать статьи по этой архитектуре в них много полезного.